# Delete property of created class object

Tags: c++, new-operator, delete-operator

If I create a class with `new` operator:

```
MyClass *myClass = new MyClass();
```

and then:

```
myClass.data = new int[2];
```

Do I need also delete `myClass.data` or just `delete myClass`?

Comment: General rule: every `new` must be paired with a `delete`, so yes, for your code to be correct you need to explicitly `delete` both. Or, better, use containers that manage this for you. Do you really need to use `new` in the first place in either of these examples? For `data`, the obvious suggestion is to use `std::vector`. For `new MyClass`, why use `new` at all?

Comment: I use it in microcontroller, so no `std::vector`. And I pass pointer of `myClass` to another function as callback value, so it has to be created with `new`. Which containers do you mean?

Comment: Hm, maybe no `std::vector`, but if your C++ runtime implementation for the microcontroller supports heap allocation, then you can write a simple `vector`-like container, or I bet find a widely used library for this. And passing a pointer or reference to an object around certainly doesn't mean it has to be on the heap. I fear this will lead to a long discussion not well suited to the comments though.

Comment: And how can I achieve this without using global variables?

Answer (score 3):

> Do I need also delete myClass.data or just delete myClass?

If you have manually allocated a resource using `new`/`new[]`, you will need to *manually* release it by `delete`/`delete[]`. This is a typical source of lifetime issues in C++, which memory handling abstractions as in STL containers and via smart pointers such as `std::share_ptr` and `std::unique_ptr` alleviates.

If a class type manually (raw pointers and `new`/`new[]`) handles its resources and the lifetime of it, you should consider apply [RAII - resource acquisition is initialization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_acquisition_is_initialization) to lower the risk of lifetime issues (as you are already down the path of manual lifetime management). This basically means that initialization of a `MyClass` object should also be where resource allocation occurs, and likewise destruction of a `MyClass` object should be where resources are released:

```
class MyClass {
    int* data;
 public:
    MyClass() : data(new int[2]) {}
    ~MyClass() { delete[] data; }
    // ... public API for working with 'data'.
};

int main() {
    MyClass m{}; // construction allocates the *m.data resource on the heap
}  // destruction of 'm' releases the *m.data resource
```